# How do i save multiple objects into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular, object

I have this object after click the save button.

```
{description: "ghhg", dateSelected: "2020-02-27", startDate: "2020-02-27", company_id: "2", hr_id: 
72, …}
```

But whenever i click on save, it gives me a new object instead of storing it in array.
The question is how can i store each object inside an array to get

```
[
{description: "ghhg", dateSelected: "2020-02-27", startDate: "2020-02-27", company_id: "1" …},
{description: "grrrhhg", dateSelected: "2020-03-27", startDate: "2020-03-27", company_id: "2" …},
{description: "ghrtrhg", dateSelected: "2020-04-27", startDate: "2020-04-27", company_id: "2",  …},
.
.
.
]
```

This is my code

```
saveHolidays(hols : []){
 this.holidays.hr_id = this.hrID.id;
 this.getHolidayDate = this.holidays.dateSelected.split(" to ");
 this.holidays.startDate = this.getHolidayDate[0];
 this.holidays.endDate = this.getHolidayDate[1];
 this.getHols = this.holidaysData;
 this.holiday_date = [];
 this.holidaysArray = [];
 var tempHolidays = [];
 this.getHols.forEach((element,key) => {
   if(element.startDate){
     this.holiday_date.push({startDate : element.startDate, endDate : element.endDate, company_id : 
  element.company_id})
   }
 });
 var getElement = [];
 let getStartDate = this.holiday_date.map(element => {
 getElement.push(element.startDate, element.company_id);
 return getElement;
 });

 for(var i = 0; i < getStartDate.length; i++){
  var isStartDatePresent = getStartDate[i].includes(this.holidays.startDate);
  var isCompanyIdPresent = getStartDate[i].includes(+this.holidays.company_id);
 }
 if(isStartDatePresent == true && isCompanyIdPresent == true ){
   this.snotifyService.error('Holiday Already Exist');    
 }else{
   hols = this.holidays;
   for(var i = 0; i < hols.length; i++){
     this.holidaysArray.push(hols[i]);
   }

  return this.holidaysArray
 }
}
```

Comment: `this.holidaysArray = [];` try to remove this from your code

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty, but if I remember correctly, JS arrays don't have fixed widths, so you might be able to push each saved holiday to an externally instantiated array or return one and set the desired external array to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are reinitializing your array every time you click on save button by writing `this.holidaysArray`.
Removing it might solve your problem.

Comment: @ M Fuat NUROĞLU, I removed it, but it stores current object passed from the save button. Its is not storing previous object from the save button. How can i store both the previous and current objects

Answer (score 0):

Set `this.holidaysArray` to an array **ONLY IF** it not already an `Array`.

```js
/* REPLACE */
    this.holidaysArray = []
/* WITH */
  if (!Array.isArray(this.holidaysArray)) {
    this.holidaysArray = []
  }
```

Also, I highly recommend using a test-framework like [`Jest`](https://jestjs.io/) to test your code.

Good Luck...